# Can you add a colon before quotations instead of a comma?

Tags: dialogue

Is it possible to add a colon instead of a comma before quotations?

Like this:

Person A said: "Blah Blah Blah."

Not as in theatrical performance, but as used in an story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is legitimate in some cases, and, truth be told, there are instances when it is preferable to a comma. Such as:

> Upon giving it some thought, Person A divested himself of the
>   following remark: "Well, you know. That's just the way it is, I
>   suppose, as you might say."

Or:

> Person A kept uttering all kinds of banalities, such as: "And what
>   does that have to do with the price of beans, if I may ask?"

Comment: Do you know of any rules that might guide the choice?

Comment: Instinctive, I think. I may be wrong.